# Java spring boot + spring batch: Process huge amount information

Tags: architecture, java-8

I have to create a Java 8 batch process (with spring boot and spring batch) that will perform the following (details for 1 execution):

- Get information from N different information sources (3 web services, 3 different databases) for which I see that I will need to launch over 5 different queries, call about 14 methods of services. I have calculated that the volume of information would be about 500,000 to 1,000,000 information data to be processed in total.
- Process information (simple mathematical calculations, but it is necessary to have available all the amount of previous information).
- Make multiples calculations.
- Save the results in database.

This process is dependent on certain input data that will cause the process to run 23 times concurrently at a given time of the day (different executions with different base data, there are no problems in terms of getting or processing the information, since it is not common information).

The problem that I see is related to the volume of information to manipulate to ultimately perform the calculations and I am not clear how and where to manipulate the information. I see some options like:

- Directly in Java: I understand this is not an option since it could have performance problems with the JVM (Stackoverflow, etc).
- Use a no SQL database: It could be interesting, although I'm not sure.
- Cache system: It could be interesting, although I'm not sure.
- Temporary tables against some DB: This option seemed interesting to me, I could insert the whole set of information in temporary tables and perform the same calculations using query's to obtain the final results.

Any ideas about an alternative or system that i could use to manipulate the set of information?

Thank you!!

Comment: This question is far too broad. 1M integers e.g. are absolutely **no problem** for the jvm, you can do fancy computations on that amount of data in far less than a second. Before worrying about performance implement it at least once to see wether or not there even is any problem at hand. Then you can come back and explain in more detail what data you have and where you are struggling.

Comment: The issue is that the information retrieved are not basic types, all of them are complex objects that I need to store, that's where I worry that having lists with sizes as large as 1,000,000 items and go over them may not be optimal and I will run into problems.

Comment: Even then 1000bytes per "complex object" would result in 1GB of RAM usage, that is "nothing". My point is: it is absolutely impossible to give performance advice if you do not yet face any performance problem because right now there is no way of telling what you want and need to perform better at _something_.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/). It has different components which covers all your requirements: [web service call](http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html), [SQL](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) / [JPA](http://camel.apache.org/jpa.html) etc.

Camel can handle big amounts of data and it offers some nice features which will make this task easier, like `streaming` and `split`.